# Is it possible to store a button value from a click event on a global variable using a callback function?

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm trying to store the value from one of three buttons in a variable called "**playerScore**", so it can be compared to another variable. However, the code below is returning "undefined" instead of the actual value of the button clicked by the user.

I'm using a callback function in order to retrieve the value from the click event. **If I simply console.log the event, it runs**. However if I try to store it in the global variable "playerScore" and then console.log it, it doesn't.

I'm sure there's a better and simpler way to do it, but I'm out of ideas. Any help is highly appreciated.

If I run the code below, the function returns "**undefined**":

```js
// Gets player choice from button click (iterates nodelist of buttons)
let playerChoice;
function getPlayerChoice() {
    const playerButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
    for (i of playerButtons) {
        (function(i) {
            i.addEventListener('click', function() {
              playerChoice = i.innerText;
            });
        })(i);     
    }
    console.log(playerChoice);
}
```

If I run the code below, it works and console logs the value of the button click:

```js
function getPlayerChoice() {
    const playerButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
    for (i of playerButtons) {
        (playerChoice = function(i) {
            i.addEventListener('click', function() {
                console.log(i.innerText);
            });
        })(i);     
    }
}
```

The getPlayerChoice() function gets called in the following function:

```js
function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {

    // Gets player and computer choices
    playerSelection = getPlayerChoice();
    computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
}
```

Comment: Well how do you expect that variable to be set before any button has been clicked?

Comment: A callback function is only run when a button is pressed. In your first example, the `console.log` is evaluated before any button is pressed, and is therefore printing `undefined.`

Comment: and where do you call `getPlayerChoice()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Console.log()` after you pressed the button, not before that

```js
function getPlayerChoice() {
    let playerChoice;
    const playerButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");//get all buttons elements
    playerButtons.forEach((button) => {
      button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        //this code runs after you press a button
        playerChoice = button.innerText;
        console.log(playerChoice);
      });
    });
}

getPlayerChoice();//call function once, not on every button press
```

```html
<button class="btn">button1</button>
<button class="btn">button2</button>
<button class="btn">button3</button>
<button class="btn">button4</button>
<button class="btn">button5</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, the `console.log` is being evaluated before any button is pressed, and will therefore print `undefined`.

To print a meaningful value, the logging of the choice must occur after a button press, like so:

```js
let playerChoice;

function bindEventListeners() {
    const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
    for (var i of btns) {
        (function(i) {
            i.addEventListener('click', function() {
              playerChoice = i.innerText;
              logChoice();
            });
        })(i);     
    }    
}

function logChoice() {
  console.log(playerChoice);
}

bindEventListeners();
```

```html
<button class="btn">one</button>
<button class="btn">two</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't see the playerChoice because you print it before a button is pressed. Split the function into two parts:

- one to add event listeners to the buttons
- one to get the playerChoice value

```js
const playerButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
const getScoreButton = document.getElementById("getScore");
let playerChoice;

playerButtons.forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener("click", function() {
    playerChoice = this.innerText;
    console.log('click:', playerChoice);
  });
});

getScoreButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log('get playerChoice:', playerChoice);
});
```

```html
<button class="btn">Alpha</button>
<button class="btn">Beta</button>
<button class="btn">Gamma</button>
<button class="btn">Delta</button>
<br />
<br />
<button id="getScore">Get score</button>
<span></span>
```